# Jquery mobile fails to load styles after change page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

Am creating a mobile application using jquery mobile but after loading an external page(loggedin.html) via changePage the javascript file in the external page arent loaded but only do so after refreshing the page(loggedin.html...loaded via changePage).How can the external script be loaded without page refresh

I have two sets of file: 
index.html and loggedin.html.

CODE:
1.index.html

```
<body>

<div data-role="page" id="indexpage">
  <div data-role="content">
   <a href=""  id="next" data-role="button">Load page 2</a>
 </div>  
</div>

<script src="custom/scripts/index.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>  
</body>
```

The script (index.js)

```
$('document').ready(function(){
$('#next').click(function(){
$.mobile.changePage('loggedin.html')

});
});
```

2.Loggedin.html

```
<body>
 <div data-role="page" id="loggedin">
  <div data-role="content">
  You are in
 </div>  
</div>
<script src="custom/scripts/loggedin.js" type="text/javascript" ></script> 
</body>
```

Script(loggedin.js)

```
$('document').ready(function(){

$('document').on("pageshow","#loggedin",function(){

console.log('loaded');

});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Base on this source : http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/faq/scripts-and-styles-not-loading.html

> The simplest approach when building a jQuery Mobile site is to reference the same set of stylesheets and scripts in the head of every page. If you need to load in specific scripts or styles for a particular page, we recommend binding logic to the pageinit event (details below) to run necessary code when a specific page is created (which can be determined by its id attribute, or a number of other ways).

Comment: I have tried passing the (<script src="custom/scripts/loggedin.js" type="text/javascript" ></script> ) before the close of page div but it returns an error that synchronous http request is deprecated...

Comment: I have found out a solution by passing the   (($('document').on("pageshow","#loggedin",function(){
console.log('loaded');
});))  After the data-role header(in loggedin.html)....But  will the cordova accept this since ill be using phonegap to package the application

Comment: If your solution works, you should post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is  : on the next page that is (loggedin.html)..That is placing the script on the page after the (data-role content/footer)

```
<body>
 <div data-role="page" id="loggedin">

<div data-role="content">

 You are in
 </div>  
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#loggedin').on("pagecreate",function(){

console.log('loaded');
......{Continue with stuff}
});

</script>
</div>

</body>
```